# Can men with Klinefelter syndrome produce chromosomally normal sperm?

Tags: genetics, meiosis, sex-chromosome

Individuals with [Klinefelter syndrome](https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/condition/klinefelter-syndrome) are XXY. Even though sperm counts are low some individuals can generate enough to be used in IVF and have offspring.

Does this mean that when sperm are formed, the process works correctly to separate all 3 of them and only sperm with a single sex chromosome are formed?

(Excluding same genetic issues happening again of course)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! I've edited your question in a way that I hope improves clarity — please re-edit if I've changed your meaning. Note that we encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: Seems like there are some hypotheses about this mechanism. This might be interesting: https://www.fertstert.org/article/S0015-0282(12)00654-1/pdf